# Как скрыть часть тела персонажа для камеры?

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр

Практикую игру от первого лица. Хочу понять, как убрать или скрыть части тела с виду от камеры.
Подумал, что настройка **Near** на камере поможет это убрать. Возможно это банальная вещь, но мне это немного сложно понять.

Хочу в будущем сделать игру с возможность онлайн. Сложно ли сделать так, чтобы у игрока была игра от первого лица видны только руки, а остальные игроки видели полностью модель игрока?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: По хорошему - это разные модели, "себя" отрисовываем моделью без тела(только руки), остальных - полноценной моделью. Ваш подход - минус к производительности

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, т. е можно сделать, чтобы "капсула", двигалась по оси Y вместе с руками?

Comment: Т.е. рисуется модель у которой есть только руки, а тела вообще нет, и используется в качестве модели "себя" :) что за капсула - я не очень понимаю

Answer (score 0):

Я могу порекомендовать 2 способа:

1. использовать отдельно руки и тело и скрывать от игрока, например тело, поскольку 2 разных объекта и скрыть уже можно
2. модульный персонаж, там он тоже будет состоять из нескольких объектов: отдельно руки, ноги, голова и тело, отключай что хочется

Comment: В твое случае модульный персонаж даже будет скорее всего наилучшим вариантом, чтобы его не резать можно сделать маску для текстуры и использовать один и тот же меш, но разные материалы с масками